# Entity Framework Update Methods

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, objectcontext

I have a few entities I'd like to update at the same time. However I'd like to write individual update methods in each classes partial class file, for each entity and call them all at the same time. For example:

```
public sub UpdateEntity1()
...
end sub 

public sub UpdateEntity2()
...
end sub 

public sub UpdateEntity3()
...
end sub 

public sub UpdateAll()
 UpdateEntity1()
 UpdateEntity2()
 UpdateEntity3()
end sub
```

My question is how do I manage the object context? do I create one object context in the class I'm calling UpdateAll(), then pass it as a parameter to each individual update method? Or do I create a new context for each Update? I'd like to use the same context because the object are related, and this would decrease the db calls to update all the records.

Comment: Anyone, any ideas? Was my question clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do as you said and pass the context as a parameter.  You may need to make sure your changes get tracked hough if the object gets detached from its original context.